# Fetch data by id AND String from single database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am totally new to Hibernate, Spring and postgres database world. There may be difference in "terms" using to describe.

So issue is, i want to fetch a data where it matches given "id" AND "string" using hibernate, JPA annotations in spring boot.

I know basic like `repository.findOne(id)` but i am not aware of how to get data with two parameters.

I guess i need something like, i am not sure as i am new to db world

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM student 
  WHERE type='commerce' 
  AND id='1'"
```

I thank you in advance and tutorials to study further is most welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Spring boot provides for you some automatic repositories, so you just create a interface that extends "JpaRepository" and then, create methods with a natural language.

Something like:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
    public List<Student> findByIdAndType(Long id, String type);
}
```

Later on, let's say you want to use this class:

```
@Autowired
private StudentRepository studentRepository;

public void doSomething() {
    List<Student> students = studentRepository.findByIdAndType(1, "commerce");
}
```

And no, there is no need to provide an implementation to the interface "StudentRepository", as spring data will provide it to you in behind the scenes.

More information on how this works, you can find on proper [spring-data documentarion](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories)

Cheers, Nikolas